# When to turn off AlarmManager in Android (onDestroy)

Tags: android, background, alarmmanager, ondestroy

I start broadcasting every 30sec with AlarmManager.setRepeating method. Later one I catch it with receiver and execute something. This whole process should run in background also and it should stop working either on user interaction or when application is closed (destroyed).

I tried to put code for stopping AlarmManager in onDestroy method, but this event is called occasionally. Is it the right way to stop it onDestroy or is there something more convinient?

I read documentation and it said:
Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed...
but later on it said:
There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method

Another problem is because even if onDestroy is called it is not executed fully. I put several Log.d inside and i can see only one of them.

Comment: Do you have only one activity?

Answer (score 0):

first you must put this before `onCreate` method

```
public static AlarmManager am;
public static PendingIntent sender;
```

and in `onDestroy` method you can put:

```
am.cancel(sender);
```

To cancel AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly how I did in my code. Problem is that onDestroy is called occasionally and sometimes even if it is called, AlarmManager is not stopped. I put Log.d, then cancel, then again Log.d. I can only see first Log.d message.

Comment: welcome and please put my answer as correct answer and rate my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a global object of `PendingIntent` and where you want to stop just call its cancel method by the same reference of `PendingIntent` object.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

onPause() is the last method that's guaranteed to be called before the process can be killed—if the system must recover memory in an emergency, then onStop() and onDestroy() might not be called. Therefore, you should use onPause() to write crucial persistent data (such as user edits) to storage.

onPause() will be the last method to be called in low memory situation. But if the user is trying to force stop application through settings->Apps->AppName->Forcestop, then even onPause won't be called.

Comment: I do not want to use onPause, because onPause is happening when ever i press home button. I want this to run in background also. I provide a functionality to user to stop it, but if he forgot I want to do it programmatically.